# Flow: On Lead Conversion, Create Opp and add Product

Tags: visual-workflow

Once a lead is converted to a contact, I would like an opportunity to automatically be created. I would like the same product to be added to that opportunity every time, with the option to add or change a product manually. I am currently able to successfully create the opportunity on conversion, but I can't seem to figure out how to add the one product I need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to use [edit] and show your Flow and where you are stuck. Note that you'll want a record-triggered flow on Opportunity to a) add a Pricebook, then query for PricebooEntry, then add OpportunityLineItem

Comment: Awesome, thank you for those steps - I used them to create the flow and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Record-triggered (after) flow on `Opportunity`
- Update Opportunity with a valid `Pricebook2Id`
- Use `Get Records` element to query for a `PricebookEntry` (a junction record between `Pricebook2` and `Product2`) that matches the Opportunity's pricebook and the desired product
- Use a `Create Records` element that builds an `OpportunityLineItem` that points at the parent `Opportunity` and the fetched `PricebookEntry`. Add a `Quantity` and `UnitPrice`

*Note that the Flow should be filtered to know if it is triggered via a Lead Conversion, otherwise, it will add an OLI for every new Opportunity, including those created in the UX.*